# 0 accepted out of 460? Will my shares be accepted eventually?

Tags: mining-profitability, scrypt

I just started mining on Slush Pool using `Macminer` with a CPU. I am getting a hashrate of 12.28kH/s with the `Scrypt hash algorithm`, which I guess is not a big rate at all.

I am wondering about the acceptance bit, do I have to wait for the whole block to finish, so I can get the acceptance and shares, or does this mean I'm wasting my time and it's not going to be accepted?

Comment: What coin are you mining, and in what pool?

Comment: scrypt, connected to http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332

Comment: which is Slush Pool

Comment: they are mining bitcoins, SHA-256. I don't think you'll get any shares accepted. SHA-256 is for ASICs. Find yourself some scrypt coin with low difficulty. http://www.coinwarz.com/

Comment: Are you mining with CPU? Then better yet mine Primecoin.

Answer (score 3):

If you're scrypt mining a SHA256d coin, you will probably never get any shares accepted. You need to use the mining algorithm the coin uses.